# Get pContext in Try/Catch handler?

Tags: c++, windows

When an exception happens, as you know, it passes pContext to the SEH. Is there anyways to access the pContext in a Try/Catch? I guess I could have the exception class grab it when being initiated but that would only work for that class and not for every exception.

Comment: there is no SEH in C++ as such..I assume you are talking about MFC, is that correct?

Comment: Try/Catch uses SEH. I am wondering how to access pContext passed to SEH from the Try/Catch.

Comment: No, try/catch uses some platform dependent operation. You need to clarify that by saying "On Windows/in MFC/in etc., exceptions pass..."

Comment: You are getting confused between "Exceptions" a C++ concept and "Structured Exceptions" a windows concept. You need to clearly articulate what you are trying to do and which concept you are trying to utilize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what you're looking for...

THE Guide for SEH: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx

Have a look to that as well:
http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=mingw-seh
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51(VS.80).aspx

Note: take care depending on the version of your compiler C++ exceptions and SEH exceptions might not be handle all together: http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2002/08/15/visual-c-exception-handling/

Comment: GetThreadContext() I basically want to call that on the current thread before the exception occurred. Windows already does this when an exception occurs and passes it to the SEH.
But I am guessing the compilers don't support this.

Comment: Are you trying to log the call stack?
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-266006.html